# Is using multiple base pages with inheritance the right choice?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Should I be using multiple base pages with inheritance or is there a better strategy?

Contrived Example:

Currently I have 20 webpages and they all use my base-page "BasePage".

ie.) Page1 : BasePage

BasePage provides functions:

- Function1()
- Function2()
- Function3()

Now I decide that 5 of my 20 webpages require the BasePage functions as well as 3 additional functions and a Page_Load():

- Function4()
- Function5()
- Function6()
- Page_Load()

Do I now create another base page like this:

MySecondBasePage : BasePage

and then put Function4(), Function5(), Function6() and Page_Load() in it?

Or is there a better/"proper" strategy to doing this? Should I be using classes?

Comment: +1 Mausimo I cannot see you resolving the situation with out going for MySecondBasePage : BasePage . Myself will be happy to see if their is another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Inheritance is not just about re-use (since we have other ways to do that), but also about managing complexity. This is a nice simple hierarchy that (assuming your real names are a bit better than "SecondPageBase") will help make it clear what is happening where, and why.

Comment: Thank-you for your reply, and yes, my real names are a lot better :).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, creating `MySecondBasePage` which inherits from `BasePage` seems to be the right way in your case.
Then, in the 5 "special" pages, you inherit `MySecondBasePage` instead of `BasePage`.

This is the proper class hierarchy for your situation.